# Printing elements of array using ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, erb

I'm trying to print a simple array defined in my controller into my view with a new line for each element. But what it's doing is printing the whole array on one line.

Here's my controller:

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @todo_array = [ "Buy Milk", "Buy Soap", "Pay bill", "Draw Money" ]
  end
end
```

Here's my view:

```
<%= @todo_array.each do |t| %>
<%= puts t %><\br>
<% end %>
```

Here's the result:

```
<\br> <\br> <\br> <\br> ["Buy Milk", "Buy Soap", "Pay bill", "Draw Money"]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Erb, the templating engine you're using in your views, has a few different ways of embedding ruby code inside templates.

When you put code inside `<%= %>` blocks, erb evaluates the code inside and prints the value of the last statement in the HTML.  Since `.each` in ruby returns the collection you iterated over, the loop using `<%= %>` attempts to print a string representation of the entire array.

When you put code inside `<% %>` blocks, erb just evaluates the code, not printing anything. This allows you to do conditional statements, loops, or modify variables in the view.

You can also remove the `puts` from `puts t`. Erb knows to try to convert the last value it saw inside `<%= %>` into a string for display.

Answer (score 7):

Just try:

`<%= @todo_array.join('<br />').html_safe %>`

instead of

```
<%= @todo_array.each do |t| %>
   <%= puts t %><\br>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6):

Hey why are you putting '=' sign in first line. <% %> are used for telling rails that string under this is ruby code,evaluate it. Where as <%= %> this tells rails that string in these tags is in ruby, evaluate it and print the result in html file too.

Hence try to inspect your code you are writing

`<%=` @todo_array.each do |t| %>
while this line is only for iterating over @todo_array hence we wont be in need to print that line. So final code should be

```
<% @todo_array.each do |t| %>
 <%= puts t %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Like your own answer says, there's no need for the `puts` - `<%=` prints the result.

Answer (score 5):

Two issues with your view:

1. you are using "<%=" where you should be using "<%".
2. you don't need 'puts'

This should improve your results:

```
<% @todo_array.each do |t| %>
  <%= t %><\br>
<% end %>
```

I would further consider using some HTML structure to better structure your todo list (instead of using br tag at the end of lines), perhaps an un-ordered list like so:

```
<ul>
  <% @todo_array.each do |t| %>
    <li><%= t %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the equal sign from your each statement:

```
<% @todo_array.each do |t| %>
  <%= t %><\br>
<% end %>
```